# Uploading a file with Spring rest controller does not work

Tags: spring, resttemplate, spring-restcontroller

I am writing two applications that should communicate over REST. Both applications are SpringBoot applications. The most web services are working fine but I have some problems with the uploading of a file. This is my rest controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(PathConstants.SERVER_PACKAGING_INTERFACE + "/**")
public class PackagingCommunication {
    //@PostMapping(PathConstants.SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE)
    @RequestMapping(name = PathConstants.SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE, method = RequestMethod.POST, headers=("content-type=multipart/*"))
    public ResponseEntity<String>  uploadFileInStorage(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
            RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();
            String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
            //storageService.saveInputStreamInStorage(inputStream, fileName);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).build(); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
    }
}
```

My client with rest template:

```
public void uploadeFileToStorage(File file, String serverUrl) {
    try{
        final MultiValueMap<String, Object> parameterMap = createMultipartFileParam(file.getAbsolutePath());
        parameterMap.add("file", file);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        //headers.set("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        //headers.set("Accept", "text/plain");
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

        String url = serverUrl + PathConstants.SERVER_PACKAGING_INTERFACE + PathConstants.SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE;
        restTemplate = getRestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(parameterMap, headers), 
                String.class);
        System.out.println(response.getHeaders().getAccept());
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        // Delete the file from the temporary directory of the client.
        file.delete();
    }
}
```

I get a http error code `400`. The commented lines show statements I tried to solve the problem. Then I wrote a html formular for trying to communicate with the web service without my Java program.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://localhost:9292/serverPackaging/uploadFile">
            <table>
                <tr><td>File to upload:</td><td><input type="file" name="file" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

It does also not work. I get the error "Required request part 'file' is not present". I don't know what to do. The html formular is not important. Really important is the communication between the two applications with the help of rest template.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 null
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:653)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:531)
    at de.feu.kdmp4.packagingtoolkit.client.operations.classes.ServerCommunicationOperationsImpl.uploadeFileToStorage(ServerCommunicationOperationsImpl.java:314)
    at de.feu.kdmp4.packagingtoolkit.client.operations.facade.OperationsFacade.uploadeFileToStorage(OperationsFacade.java:49)
    at de.feu.kdmp4.packagingtoolkit.client.service.classes.ArchiveServiceImpl.addFileReference(ArchiveServiceImpl.java:69)
    at de.feu.kdmp4.packagingtoolkit.client.service.facades.ServiceFacade.addFileReference(ServiceFacade.java:48)
    at de.feu.kdmp4.packagingtoolkit.client.view.prime.managedBeans.InformationPackageCreationBean.createInformationPackage(InformationPackageCreationBean.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:814)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

´

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,
Christopher

Comment: Please post the complete Stacktrace.

Comment: I am sorry. I forgot the stacktrace. Here it comes:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust your @RequestMapping annotation. Replace `name` field with `value`

Below is an example which works for me quite well, maybe it can help you. Just ignore the context for the code example:

```
@PostMapping("/recipe/{id}/image")
public String handleImagePost(@PathVariable String id, 
@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

    log.debug("received a file for recipe with id: " + recipeId);

    try{
        Recipe recipe = recipeRepository.findById(recipeId).get();
        Byte[] byteObjects = new Byte[file.getBytes().length];

        int i = 0;

        for(byte b: file.getBytes()){
            byteObjects[i++] = b;
        }

        recipe.setImage(byteObjects);
        recipeRepository.save(recipe);

    }catch(IOException e){
        log.error("Error occured while persisting the file. " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "redirect:/recipe/" + id + "/show";
}
```

And the corresponding HTML:

```
<form  action="http://localhost/recipe/1/image" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label class="control-label">Select File</label>
            <input id="file" name="file" type="file" class="file">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately  it does not work. I still get the same error. Required request part 'file' is not present and I used your code minus the recipe-logic.

Comment: I deleted @RequestParam("file") and now the method is called but the parameter file is null.

Comment: In another project, your code is working. I think the error is something else that has nothing to do with the file upload. Thank you for your help.